# How to use deepLink in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink

**PLEASE HELP MEEEE**

In my application i want use **DeepLink** and for this i write below code.
But when run application **not suggest** my application and just show in Chrome browser !

**My Url :** `sosapp://sosapp/hashcode/ghfhgfhgf?`

**My codes :**

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity.LandingActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
<activity
    android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="sosapp" android:host="sosapp"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

How can i fix it and when click on this Url from mobile, **suggest** my app ?

Comment: you want open your app from other app?

Comment: Code seems to be fine,  may be chrome might have chosen as the default app to launch, so next time it won't ask. u might need to reset this by go to setting of device.

Comment: @lib4, i remove chrome default app from setting. but not open again! how can i fix it?!

Comment: @Radesh, i want open above url by my app with deepLink

Comment: do you use android O?

Comment: @Rainmaker, No . Device : Samsun . OS : android 7.0

Comment: how do u test this deep link is working or not?

Comment: i share this url in social network, and when click on link open in chrome and not show suggest my app! can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried use your link in my Activity and works fine.

my Activity Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="sosapp"
                android:scheme="sosapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and my intent used to call the activity

```
val action = Intent() 
action.data = Uri.parse("sosapp://sosapp/hashcode/ghfhgfhgf?")
startActivity(action)
```

Comment: kotlin code. Its seems Intent action = new Intent() in java

Answer (score 0):

Add pathPattern to your data tag like below:

```
  <data
                android:host="sosapp"
                android:pathPattern="/*"
                android:scheme="sosapp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding label, it's mandatory for higher versions of android. See example from the docs. They always include a label for `intent-filter`

```
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
```